# Is there a way to find out which button of a TButtonGroup was clicked?

Tags: delphi, button

My application uses a TButtonGroup control. I assign to each button an event handler: doClick. By assigning information to each button (`Pointer (i)`) I can figure out which button was called. This is the code:

```
procedure TVector_Menu.Synchronize (rows, cols: Int32);
var btn: TGrpButtonItem; 
    i: Int32;
begin
   ButtonGroup.Items.Clear;
   Self.Rows := rows;
   Self.Cols := cols;
   for i := 0 to rows * cols - 1 do
   begin
      btn := Buttongroup.Items.Add;
      btn.Data       := Pointer (i);
      btn.ImageIndex := i;
      btn.OnClick    := doClick;
   end; // for
   Self.ClientHeight :=  4 + rows * ButtonGroup.ButtonHeight;
   Self.ClientWidth  := 22 + cols * ButtonGroup.ButtonWidth;
end; // Synchronize //

procedure TVector_Menu.doClick (Sender: TObject);
var btn: TGrpButtonItem; 
    i, r, c: Int32;
begin
   btn := (Sender as TGrpButtonItem); // @@@ TButtonGroup
   i := Int32 (btn.Data);
   get_rc (i, r, c);
   if Assigned (FOnClick)
      then FOnClick (Sender, @FButton_Matrix [r, c]);
end; // doClick //
```

When doClick is called I get an Invalid Typecast at the line labeled '@@@'. The typecast is correct when I use TButtonGroup for btn as well as in the typecast, but this one does not contain a data property and that would not have been of much use anyway.

As a Test I assigned an OnClick event handler to the TButtonGroup control and I noticed that when I click a button, first the button event handler is called and next the TButtonGroup, containing the button, event handler.

Question: is there a way to find out which button of a TButtonGroup was clicked?

Using Delphi XE on Windows 7/64

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get an invalid typecast exception because `Sender` is in fact the `TButtonGroup` and is not a `TGrpButtonItem`. What this means is that you need to use a different event handler for each button if you are going to use `TGrpButtonItem.OnClick`.

In your situation it is clear that you should use the [`TButtonGroup.OnButtonClicked`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ButtonGroup.TButtonGroup.OnButtonClicked) event which does provide the button index.

There is a potential pitfall here, however, that you need to make sure you avoid. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ButtonGroup.TButtonGroup.OnButtonClicked) states:

> Occurs when a button is clicked, if the OnClick event is not present.

In other words the `OnButtonClicked` event will only fire if you have not assigned an `OnClick` event handler for either the button group or the button item.

Comment: Ah, and I see that I probably should have used `ButtonGroupButtonClicked`. That one returns an index. Start trying that.

Answer (score 1):

use...

```
procedure TfrmFattern.ButtonGroup1ButtonClicked(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer);
begin
  StatusBar1.SimpleText := IntToStr(Index + 1);
end;
```